# Многостраничный сайт с помощью php

Tags: php, html, css

Делаю сайт, который состоит из  5-6 страниц и header и footer на всех страницах одинаковые, изменяется только section. До этого я как-то не работал с многостраничными сайтами и нашел способ не копировать одно header и footer в каждую созданную страницу. Я создал отдельный файл с header, вырезал кусок кода из оригинального документа и заместо этого куска в оригинальном документе вставил:

```html
<?php 
    include('header.php'); // Путь до документа где находится header. 
 ?>
```

И таким образом я заместо целого куска кода в странице пишу эту строчку, а header и footer вырезаны и распределены по отдельным файлам. И вопрос том, что нормальный ли это способ? Или есть какие-то более современные способы по написанию многостраничных сайтов без копирования одних и тех же кусков кода.

Comment: Есть. Называется MVC

Comment: Почти все фреймворки и CMS по этой концепции (MVC) работают. Ну, очень много, скажем так

Comment: А вообще зависит от сайта и количества страниц. Если там страниц 5: главная, небольшие новости, контакты, ещё один раздельчик - то и такой способ вполне. Потому что заморачиваться с MVC или фреймворком ради 5 разделов маленьких - нет смысла

Comment: зато какой-нибудь smarty прикрутить полезно. там и вопрос подключения хэдеров и футеров либо инклудами либо наследованием решается. Да и в целом большой шаг в разделении логики от представления.

Answer (score 4):

Вам уже написали в комментариях что в целом не плохо было бы понять что такое MVC.
К вашему методу Вы можете ещё добавить rewrite чтобы не прописывать require_once для header и footer.

То есть например вы заходите на URi Вашего сайта /contacts а отрабатывает скрипт router.php в нём проверка вида(только из переменной $uri предваритеьно ведущий слеш нужно удалить)

```
if (is_file($uri . ".php")) {
  require_once("header.php");
  require_once($uri . ".php");
  require_once("footer.php");
} else {
  //тут вывод ошибки 404 или что то такое
}
```